# checking for specific characters in String using matches()

Tags: java

What im trying to do is reject any string that contains characters outside a-z, 0-9 or _

I tried using the match function below as id seen elsewhere but i cant get it to work correctly. It will either tell me the string is fine when its not, or it will tell me its not fine when it is.

```
public static Boolean checkc(String word) {
    String w = word;
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
        if (w.substring(i, i).matches("[A-Za-z0-9_]")) {
            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The logic might be wrong now because I've fiddled with it trying to get it working but to be fair, it wasnt working in the first place. Im checking a few things in the function thats calling this, so i just need to know if it string is fine given the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static boolean check(String word) {
    return word.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+");
}
```

this method returns true when `word` string contains no single character described in the square bracket, ^ regex symbol means same as logical ! (in example !true == false). Plus symbol `+` after square bracket means that **one** symbol `[]` could repeat one or more time.

javadoc link to [Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (regex explanations and examples)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/) convenient online regex debug tool

Comment: Thanks, i had to remove the ^ and it started working. I dont get why, but its working now at least.

Answer (score 3):

The end index argument to `substring` is exclusive, so `substring(i, i)` always returns a 0 length string. You could fix this by using `substring(i, i+1)`, but there's no reason to use a loop here. You can just use `word.matches("[A-Za-z0-9_]+")` and check the entire string at once. The regex quantifier `+` means "one or more". You could also use the quantifier `*` which means "zero or more", if the method should return true if the string is empty.

Edit: There's also another problem with your loop logic that I just noticed. Your conditional in the loop returns true the first time the condition is met:

```
for (...) {
    if ( /* condition is met */ )
       return true;
}
return false;
```

That logic only requires that the condition be met at least once, and then it returns true, but you probably meant the following:

```
for (...) {
    if (! /* condition is met */ )
       return false;
}
return true;
```

That requires that the condition be met for every character.

Answer (score 0):

> stringToCheck.String.matches("[^0-9a-zA-Z_]")

This will check whether string that needs to be matched contains any digits or alphabets and return a boolean value